# Get documents with specific value in an array inside the document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

my document is as below

```
const mailSchema = new Schema ({
from: String,
to: [{
    emailId: String,
    status: Number
}],
cc: [{
    emailId: String,
    status: Number
}],
bcc: [{
    emailId: String,
    status: Number
}],
subject: String,
content: String,
status: Number,
createdBy: Schema.Types.ObjectId
}
```

How to retrieve document where 'to.emailid' contains a given value?

I have used below code but it is not working.

const emailtext = 'test@gmail.com'
 MailSchema.find({'to.emailId': emailtext });

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: @Visrozar it return empty result set.

Comment: Well, your find query is correct. Check whether the emailtext variable has the value you want it to have and check whether that value exists in the DB

Comment: Yes, I can see that and the query you've written is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think your schema is incorrect. what you want to do is to have a document that contain an object file. But what you did is a document with an array of file objects. so i think you should remove all the square bracket in the schema, then it should look like this.

```
//Mail Schema without array of objects.
const mailSchema = new Schema ({
from: String,
to: {
       emailId: String,
       status: Number
 },
cc: {
      emailId: String,
      status: Number
 },
bcc: {
     emailId: String,
     status: Number
},
subject: String,
content: String,
status: Number,
createdBy: Schema.Types.ObjectId
}
```

However if what you really want is an array of objects, then your query should also include the index of the array you want to get the emailId from.
Example.

```
 MailSchema.find({'to[0].emailId': emailtext });
```